# How can I use Jar produced by mvn package in another Jenkins declarative pipeline stage?

Tags: java, maven, docker, jenkins, devops

I'm trying to build CI/CD pipeline with Jenkins for Maven project. I can't seem to find any decent examples on how to use .jar file produced by mvn package in another Jenkins declarative pipeline stage. I need the jar file to make an docker-image before uploading it to docker-registry. Here's my relevant parts of jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages{
    stage('Build Jar'){
        agent {
          docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine'
            args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2'
          }
        }
        steps {
            sh 'mvn package'
            stash includes: 'target/*.jar', name: 'targetfiles'
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
        agent {
            node {
                label 'DockerDefault'
            }
         }

      steps {
            script{
                def image = docker.build("image-name:test", ' .')
            }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
#install OS
FROM centos
#install java
RUN yum install -y java
#make directory structure to store temporary files
RUN mkdir -p /store
#put jar into container
ADD target/AdWordsProducer-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar adwordsproducer.jar
#run jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/adwordsproducer.jar"]
```

**EDIT 1----------------------------------------------------------------------:**

Laszlos answer did the trick, as I noticed that my .jar file was under different name than dockerfile assumed. 
Here is my working final jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages{
    stage('Build Jar'){
        agent {
          docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine'
            args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2'
          }
        }
        steps {
            sh 'mvn package'
            stash includes: 'target/*.jar', name: 'targetfiles'
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
        agent {
            node {
                label 'DockerDefault'
            }
         }

      steps {
            script{
                unstash 'targetfiles'
                sh 'ls -l -R'
                def image = docker.build("image-name:test", ' .')
            }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And modified dockerfile:

```
#install OS
FROM centos
#install java
RUN yum install -y java
#make directory structure to store temporary files
RUN mkdir -p /store
#put jar into container
#ADD target/AdWordsProducer-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar adwordsproducer.jar
ADD target/AdWordsProducer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar adwordsproducer.jar
#run jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/adwordsproducer.jar"]
```

Comment: You can use the same dockerfile for all stages and just install docker cmd on it and mount the docker.sock to it.

Comment: Using the declarative syntax how can I install docker cmd and do the mounting of docker.sock?

Comment: I'll put it as an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are stashing the jar files under the name 'targetfiles'. This is good.

What I think is missing is to pop from the stash, try adding the unstash line as shown bellow. The files will be in the exact same location as when you stashed them. Under "target/" in your case.

```
stage('Deploy') {
  steps {
        script{
            unstash 'targetfiles'
            sh 'docker build image-name:test'
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: I added the unstash inside the script section, but it still fails with "ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder297706921/target/AdWordsProducer-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar: no such file or directory
script returned exit code 1"

Comment: Hm, perhaps adding an `sh 'ls -l'` before the docker build command can give some clues what files are there.

Comment: did sh 'ls -l -R' and found out there is a target folder and inside it there is file named "AdWordsProducer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" where the dockerfile expects the same file with -shaded at the end of the name

Comment: Awesome. I guess if you make the filenames match, you are golden :)

Comment: Worked! Will modify my question to include results. Unfortunately I got another error when "Notifying commit build result" to Bitbucket "java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/adwordsproducer_soLaszlo-H7SU2BEXPNCY3Z7GB2K3S4VCB6HPRJC2IWRXRA5CMYCOBZNLLQAQ/Dockerfile" but I guess that is outside of this questions scope

Comment: Awesome :) Not sure about this other one though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same dockerfile for all stages and just install docker cmd on it and mount the docker.sock to it.

Add this to the Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common && \
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/gpg | apt-key add - && \
    add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/centos trusty stable" && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y docker-ce
```

And run set the Jenkinsfile like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
       docker {
         image 'maven:3-alpine'
         args '-u root -v /root/.m2:/root/.m2 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
       }
    }
    stage('Build Jar'){
        steps {
            sh 'mvn package'
            stash includes: 'target/*.jar', name: 'targetfiles'
        }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {

      steps {
            script{
                sh 'docker build image-name:test'
            }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting an error trying to use docker.build:

/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sproducer_jenkinsdeploytest-A4VADMAFYEI7LNUGCAU3GTD55H6LWVGI5YZ6J2LWDRRHUQ5CVIAA@tmp/durable-b0a881a2/script.sh: line 1: docker: not found
script returned exit code 127

Comment: Right, you should replace it with sh 'docker build image-name:test' command. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Still getting the same error when trying the edited answer

Comment: Figured maybe using base image 'twalter/maven-docker:latest' when defining agent, that includes docker binaries, but when trying to build with sh docker.build I get "Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.29/build?"

Comment: Add '-u root' to the docker run arguments (I've edited my example as well) so it will run as root.